# How to join SQL statements with different where clause on same column of same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 statements in sqlite

1st Statement:

```
Select SUM(GrossQty) As GQTY, SUM(NetQty) As NQTY
  From NSales 
  Where IMonth=5 And IYear=2012 And IDay>15
```

Result:

> ```
> GQty  NQty
>  30    25
> ```

2nd Statement

```
Select SUM(GrossQty) As GQTY, SUM(NetQty) As NQTY
  From NSales 
  Where IMonth=6 And IYear=2012 And IDay<10
```

2nd Result:

> ```
> GQty  NQty
>  20    15
> ```

How can I combine these statements so that I get both these results added together like this?

Desired Result:

> ```
> GQty  NQty
>  50    40
> ```

Comment: opps..sorry added FROM clause

Comment: Why using join where you can add conditions in where clause I mean **IMonth IN(6,5)**

Comment: is nay solution work for you ??

Comment: Note that indenting text tags it with `<code>` tags, which isn't appropriate for sample output. Until SO supports [`<samp>`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42692/), `<blockquote><pre>` is the most appropriate mark-up. Other than that, great write-up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(a.GQTY) AS GrossQty, 
    SUM(a.NQTY) AS NQTY
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(GrossQty) AS GQTY, SUM(NetQty) AS NQTY 
    FROM   NSales 
    WHERE  IMonth = 5 AND IYear = 2012 AND IDay > 15

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(GrossQty), SUM(NetQty)
    FROM   NSales
    WHERE  IMonth = 6 AND IYear = 2012 AND IDay < 10
) a
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT 
    a.GQTY + b.GQTY AS GQTY,
    a.NQTY + b.NQTY AS NQTY
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(GrossQty) AS GQTY, SUM(NetQty) AS NQTY 
    FROM   NSales 
    WHERE  IMonth = 5 AND IYear = 2012 AND IDay > 15
) a
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(GrossQty) AS GQTY, SUM(NetQty) NQTY
    FROM   NSales
    WHERE  IMonth = 6 AND IYear = 2012 AND IDay < 10
) b
```

Or you can use `CASE` expressions and avoid having to issue two separate subselects (harder to read):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN (IMonth = 5 AND IYear = 2012 AND IDay > 15) OR
                  (IMonth = 6 AND IYear = 2012 AND IDay < 10) THEN
                  GrossQty
             ELSE 0
        END) AS GQTY, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN (IMonth = 5 AND IYear = 2012 AND IDay > 15) OR
                  (IMonth = 6 AND IYear = 2012 AND IDay < 10) THEN
                  NetQty
             ELSE 0
        END) AS NQTY
FROM NSales
```

Comment: Thanks..all are working fine.Though all the 3 solutions are giving the same result,in the third one the decimal places of NQTY seems to be be more like 61.800000000000004 where as in the other 2 its 61.8. Its not an issue..but just mentioning..thanks once again